# ASP.NET Webカスタムコントロールについて

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET Webカスタムコントロールを使用する際、ASPXファイルに下記のような
記述を追加しております。

'<%@ Register tagprefix="tagprefix名" namespace="namespace名" assembly="assembly名" %>'

上記の、「assembly="assembly名"」部分を省略することは可能でしょうか。
明示的に指定するのではなく、現在のプロジェクトのアセンブリを参照するように
することはできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

コントロールのソースコードがApp_Codeディレクトリにある場合に限ってassembly属性を省略することが出来ます。ですので「現在のプロジェクト」ではありますが、動的コンパイルされる部分のためアセンブリは異なります。

もし記述量を減らしたいのでしたらWeb.configのcontrols要素を利用した方が良いかと思います。